# I am trying to create a price calculator with checkbox's that will automatically discount the price if over a certain amount

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a pricing table where a customer can click a checkbox from each section and then see the total price and discounted price afterward. I have no experience with JS and its been a while since I have had to code.

I have spent the last day or so playing around with code and I cant seem to find a fix to this.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks');
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = 'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkproduct').click(function() {
    var totalAmount = 0;
    $('.checkproduct').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        totalAmount += parseInt($(this).val());
      }
    });
    $('#totals').val(totalAmount);
  });
});

if (totals >= 1000 && productCost < 1600) {
  discount = 0.9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Create Your Own Package</h2>
<input id="totals" type="text" value="€" />
    
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sofas')">Sofas</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Armchairs')">Armchairs</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mattresses')">Mattresses</button>
</div>

<div id="Sofas" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Sofas</h3>
      <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="400" />Sofa 1 €400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="200" />Sofa 2 €200</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="Armchairs" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Armchairs</h3>
      <table style="display:block">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="400" />Armchair 1 €400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="200" />Armchair 2 €200</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="Mattresses" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Mattresses</h3>
      <table style="display:block">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="400" />Mattress 1 €400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="200" />Mattress 2 €200</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Pretty much what I have wanted is for someone to click a checkbox and if the total is > 1000 they get no discount if it is greater than 1500 they get a 10% discount, over 2000 they get a 15% discount, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to do the calculation of the discount right when the page loads - and you don’t even have variables named `totals` and `productCost` declared at this point. The only reason this does not throw an error right there already, is that the browser automatically created a global `totals` variable from the element with that ID, but comparing an HTML element to a number makes no sense, so evaluating this expression stops when `totals >= 1000` is not true already, so it doesn’t get to the point where you try to access `productCost` next (that one _would_ throw an error.)

Comment: You obviously need to start by doing this calculation _inside_ your checkbox click handler, and not totally unrelated to anything.

Comment: Thank you @04FS , as I have said I don't know anything about JS I only started looking at JS yesterday but I will try what you have said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<html>
<body>

    <h2>Create Your Own Package</h2>
    <input id="totals" type="text" value="€" />
    <input id="discount" type="text" value="€" />

    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sofas')">Sofas</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Armchairs')">Armchairs</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mattresses')">Mattresses</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Sofas" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Sofas</h3>
          <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="400" />Sofa 1 €400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="200" />Sofa 2 €200</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="Armchairs" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Armchairs</h3>
          <table style="display:block">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="400" />Armchair 1 €400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="200" />Armchair 2 €200</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="Mattresses" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Mattresses</h3>
          <table style="display:block">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="400" />Mattress 1 €400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="200" />Mattress 2 €200</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
             $('.checkproduct').click(function(){
                var amount = 0;
                var totalBefore =0;
                var totalAmount = 0;
                var discount = 0;
                    $('.checkproduct').each(function() {
                        debugger;
                            if($(this).attr('checked')){
                                amount=parseFloat($(this).val())
                                totalBefore +=amount; 
                                if(totalBefore>=1500){
                                    totalAmount = totalBefore -(totalBefore*0.1);
                                    discount = totalBefore*0.1;
                                }
                                else if(totalBefore>=2000){
                                    totalAmount = totalBefore -(totalBefore*0.15);
                                    discount = discount*0.15;
                                }
                                else{
                                    totalAmount = totalBefore ;
                                }
                            }
                            $('#totals').val("amount = "+totalAmount);
                            $('#discount').val("discount = "+discount );
                        });
             });
      });

    if (totals >= 1000 && productCost < 1600)
    {
        discount = 0.9;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was trying to do :)

Comment: always welcome , click answer as accepted if it helps you

Comment: can you please look thee edited answer , before one has a small issue on uncheck its not going, now  it works fine

Comment: thank you, only noticed now. is there a way to separate the total and discount into a different block?

Comment: add one more input field `<input id="discount" type="text" value="€" />` in the top and return it to that `$('#totals').val("amount"+totalAmount );`  ``$('#discount').val("discount"+discount );`

Comment: Thanks @harsha , I got it sorted yesterday with a bit of playing around. Just wondering is this the correct way to implement the € in the calculation?                 
 $('#original').val("Original Price            €" +totalBefore );
$('#discount').val("Discount                    €" +discount    );
$('#totals')  .val("Total Package Price  €" +totalAmount );